# Remove multiple elements from array in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

In Lua, I know there is

```
table.remove(array, index)
```

Is there a fast way to remove and return X elements from the array (without just repeated calls to table.remove)?

Answer (score 3):

No; there is no API to remove and return several elements from a table. You can use `table.remove`, `array[index] = nil`, or resetting `array` to an empty table and repopulating (if you have majority elements to remove).